# How is shouldOverrideUrl called

Tags: android, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm totally new to android development.
Recently I'm asked to investigate something about webview loading for our app which is written by flutter, and used flutter_webview_plugin.

After I version up flutter_webview_plugin, I find there are some changes.

And there is the code in flutter_webview_plugin

```
 @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("url", url);
        data.put("type", "startLoad");
        FlutterWebviewPlugin.channel.invokeMethod("onState", data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("url", url);

        FlutterWebviewPlugin.channel.invokeMethod("onUrlChanged", data);

        data.put("type", "finishLoad");
        FlutterWebviewPlugin.channel.invokeMethod("onState", data);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        // returning true causes the current WebView to abort loading the URL,
        // while returning false causes the WebView to continue loading the URL as usual.
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        boolean isInvalid = checkInvalidUrl(url);
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("url", url);
        data.put("type", isInvalid ? "abortLoad" : "shouldStart");

        FlutterWebviewPlugin.channel.invokeMethod("onState", data);
        return isInvalid;
    }
```

I tried to search everywhere by using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading, onPageStarted,onPageFinished`, but can't find where they are called.
I think they should be used by like:

```
BrowserClient webViewClient;
webviewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()
```

or

```
webViewClient.invokeMethod('shouldOverrideUrlLoading',arg)
```

something like above. But I can't find anything.

Comment: The webview calls these methods itself, by implementing it and returning a true / false value, you can decide whether to allow the webview to load a specific url or not

Comment: a common use case to is to prevent the user from navigating away from your site

Comment: Oh, got it, thank you @SteelToe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebView calls these methods itself when a page is supposed to be loaded.

So let us say the WebView is trying to load www.google.com, the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` will get a call with the web address www.google.com passed in to the `request` argument.

You can return `true` or `false` to tell the WebView whether it should load the url, or if it should stop it.

A common use case is to prevent the user from navigating away from a specific webpage in a in app browser.

Hope this helps!!